# É permitido reclamar do site?

Tags: debate

Eu vi em algumas perguntas do meta reclamações sobre o site (não eram sugestões). É permitido isso? Não há uma área específica do site para reclamações?

Comment: É aqui mesmo. Teria sido melhor ter postado o problema. Claro que sempre tem formas e formas de fazer, sabendo postar terá boa receptividade. Reclamar por reclamar não costuma dar bom resultado.

Comment: Então, como disse o bigown, o lugar é aqui mesmo. Mas é só isso que você queria saber, ou tem também alguma reclamação?

Comment: Por que algumas perguntas ficam cinza?

Comment: Cinza? Pode citar um exemplo com link?

Comment: Não sei se é disso que você está falando, mas postagens com pontuação de -5 ou menos ficam mais apagadas.

Comment: Reclamação é uma sugestão, e de fato, uma sugestão também impõe opinião, fato ou acontecimento do autor, e o mesmo ocorre em uma reclamação.

Comment: O importante é não ofender o trabalho dos administradores e desenvolvedores do site :P

Comment: Bom, não entendi se você abandonou a discussão, mas se tiver algo a debater ou reclamar do site, é só postar aqui no meta.

Comment: Acredito que o Cinza que o Vinicius perguntou é após abrir a pergunta aqui no meta, as perguntas ficam cinzas após "lidas", pelo menos para mim.